# The .json printed data doesn't respect the dictionary order in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, package.json

I am analyzing some real-time captured data in order to parse some TLS Client Hello information.
After capturing and analyzing the data, I print out the information in an `output.txt` file as a `.json` format by using a dictionary in python.

**My question is** about the `.json` output in the `output.txt` file. The data is not being printed in order, which means it doesn't respect the order of the data in the dictionary (`output_dictionary.py`).

The dictionary that I am using for the `.json` output:

```
output_dictionary.py

HANDSHAKE = {
    "Client_Hello" : {
        'Length': 'unknown',
        'Version': 'unknown', 
        'Random': 'unknown', 
        'Session ID': 'unknown', 
        'Session ID Length': 'unknown', 
        'Cipher Suites Length': 'unknown',
        'Cipher Suites': 'unknown', 
        'Compression Method': 'unknown'
        }
    }
```

The function that fills the dictionary in order to print it as a `.json` with           `json_read("output.txt")` call:

```
def parse_client_hello(handshake):
    if isinstance(handshake.data, dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello):
        client = dpkt.ssl.TLSClientHello(str(handshake.data))
        **HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Length'] = len(client)**
        **HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Version'] = tls_dictionary('tls_version',client.version)**
        
        **HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Random'] = hexlify(client.random)**
        
        session_id, pointer = parse(client.data, 1)
        **HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Session ID'] = hexlify(session_id)**
        **HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Session ID Length'] = len(session_id)**
        
        ciphersuites, pointer1 = parse(client.data[pointer:], 2)
        ciphersuites, pretty_cipher_suites = parse_ciphers_compressions(ciphersuites, 'cipher_suites')
        **HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Cipher Suites Length'] = len(ciphersuites)**
        **HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Cipher Suites'] = pretty_cipher_suites**
        
        pointer += pointer1 
        compression_methods, pointer1 = parse(client.data[pointer:], 1)
        compression_methods, pretty_compressions = parse_ciphers_compressions(compression_methods,
            'compression_methods')
        **HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Compression Method'] = pretty_compressions**

        json_read("output.txt")
```

The `json.read` function that converts the dictionary into a `.json` format:

```
def json_read(filename):
    with open(filename, "a") as f:
        json.dump(HANDSHAKE, f, indent = 4)
```

How the data is printed in the `ouput.txt` file as a `.json` format:

```
{
    "Client_Hello": {
        "Session ID Length": 32, 
        "Length": 236, 
        "Version": "TLS 1.2", 
        "Handshake Type": "Client Hello : 1", 
        "Compression Method": [
            "null"
        ], 
        "Session ID": "3eadfb1c6243f6aa70a880af598d52873e1fe049f15c3a7e2e6f4a3e4b58fc0e", 
        "Random": "502143b34cab4a59f947a8da76f58e66215bf709e85f71f7cbfa4ead8e99736b", 
        "Cipher Suites Length": 15, 
        "Cipher Suites": [
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", 
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", 
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", 
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", 
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", 
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", 
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", 
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", 
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", 
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", 
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", 
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", 
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", 
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA", 
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `.json` printed data doesn't respect the dictionary order, which means first it should have printed the length,the version,the random..etc.
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Write your own function to print it the way you want.

Comment: Why do you need the order? JSON associative array (JS object counterpart) is unordered

Comment: JSON objects are unordered.

Comment: @ScottHunter in the json.dump(HANDSHAKE, f, indent = 4) call, doesn't it take the order of HANDSHAKE dictionary? Why should I precise it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Does that mean that I can't print them in the order that I want to? (the HANDSHAKE dictionary order)

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Python 2.7.17

Comment: Oh. Well for starters you really shouldn't be using Python 2. In any case, in Python 2, `dict` objects don't maintain insertion order, so you'd have to use an `OrderedDict`. Note, the `json` encoder does keep the dict order by default, although that isn't a guarantee, but the point is moot if you are using Python 2 (which again, you really shouldn't if you can help it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you question boils down to "Keep keys/values in same order as declared while initializing a dictionary". For this you have to use OrderedDict.
OrderedDict maintains the order in which your keys are inserted.

For your case, you can initialize your HANDSHAKE dict like below:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
client_hello_params = ['Length', 'Version', 'Random', 'Session ID', 'Session ID Length', 'Cipher Suites Length', 'Cipher Suites', 'Compression Method']
HANDSHAKE = {
"Client_Hello": OrderedDict((param, 'unknown') for param in client_hello_params)
```

Now you can keep whatever order you want by changing the order in client_hello_params list.

Printing this will print your desired result eg.

```
import json
HANDSHAKE["Client_Hello"]['Length'] = 10
print(json.dumps(HANDSHAKE))
{"Client_Hello": {"Length": 10, "Version": "unknown", "Random": "unknown", "Session ID": "unknown", "Session ID Length": "unknown", "Cipher Suites Length": "unknown", "Cipher Suites": "unknown", "Compression Method": "unknown"}}
```